# Load Windows executable at a different base address at runtime?

Tags: windows, portable-executable

Is it possible to load a Windows executable at a different base address at runtime. I don't mean compiling it with `/BASE`. It is already compiled to load at the default base address of `0x400000`. I want to see the behavior when the PE with relocation information stripped is loaded at a different base address other than the one it requested. My limited research(first 2 pages of Google) does not indicate that this is possible, but I am hoping someone could offer possible hacks.

Comment: "I want to see the behavior when the PE with relocation information stripped is loaded at a different base address other than the one it requested" - it's simple: **the program will crash** because its pointers won't be relocated and some code somewhere will try to dereference a pointer it expected to be relocated (probably some Win32 function call included in the pre-`main` executable code).

Comment: I recommend reading this article, particularly section "2.2: Handling binaries fixed addresses": https://blog.sevagas.com/PE-injection-explained

Comment: That [already happens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization), unless you changed default linker settings.  /DYNAMICBASE option.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want code that can be positioned anywhere in memory and still work whether or not you just jump into it explicitly or whether it is loaded as an executable image like any other.  It will not be dependent on the "preferred" base address, or the data in a .relocation section (if one even exists).  This code will not be reliant on any other parts of the executable image (such as the IAT, .data section or any of the various headers) however it will always be platform specific (i.e. Windows) and can be specific to some versions of Windows depending on how it is written however Windows agnostic code is achievable.

You just need your code crafted in such a way that it isn't dependent on hard-coded addresses OR hard-coded offsets from a relative image base. This is the same type of code that is used to take control of a program in security exploits.

This code almost always requires the use of explicit assembly language instructions including the entrypoint code itself.  E.g. you can't use the C Runtime's startup code by starting with a Main, WinMain, DllMain or similar. This process can be made less complex by the use of custom C MACROs and inline assembly, however you still need a general understanding of the underlying assembly instructions.

Rather than using hardcoded pointers or a relative "image" base address to reference functions and data, your functions and data pointers must be manually built relative to a spot in your entrypoint code.  This is easier than it sounds and can be as simple as a relative CALL, followed by a POP instruction to get your "base" address (X86 architecture).  Your data can then be intermixed amongst the code bytes, jumping past it as needed, pointers are built no differently than relative pointers to your functions.

By using position independent instructions and discovering the location of your entrypoint at runtime, you could theoretically take the .text section of the resulting PE image and JMP into your entry point even though the resultant EXE will also run fine.  Just be expected to do a lot of dirty work yourself, up to the point where you can resolve Windows API addresses dynamically.  This may not be for the faint of heart, however it is pretty straighforward.  This area of study will give you a deep understanding of how Windows works under the covers and you'll be a better programmer for it.

There is a plethora of information on the internet for this topic. Search for "shellcode" and tutorials on how packers/unpackers are written.  Calling windows APIs just means you need to write your own bootstrapping code to resolve these addresses at runtime; the same thing packers and unpackers do.

Recommended books describing this process, most notably import address resolution: Shellcoder's Programming Uncovered (Kaspersky), Shellcoder's Handbook (Anley), and The Rootkit Arsenal (Blunden); the latter touches a bit on C MACROs to manage complexity aspect.  Some details are discussed in the following article, [Locating KERNEL32 in ASLR memory](http://bytepointer.com/articles/locating_kernel32_in_aslr_memory.htm).

Good luck!